# IIS7 - Two Way SSL - 403.7

Tags: ssl, https, iis-7

I'm having some issues with two way SSL, hoping I can find some guidance. I've tried a lot of info I've found online, and while helpful I can't get past this issue..

First some background on what I have done and how I'm setup.

**IIS Server Setup**:

SSL Settings:

[image: SSL Settings]

Auth Settings:

[image: Auth Settings]

Mapping Config:

[image: Mapping Config]

Mapped Certs:

[image: Mapped Certs]

Bindings:

[image: Bindings]

Server Cert:

[image: Server Cert]

Server Trusted Root:

[image: Server Trusted Root]

Cert Path:

[image: Cert Path]

OK. So for starters I'm trying to get this to work on the server itself. I've imported the server cert into my personal store:

[image]

With the same root authority:

[image]

So... That should cover it, Right?!

Nope. I get this error in IE when I hit the site locally??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to use the same certificate for the server and the client. That's not how it works.

You need to have a client certificate in your personal store. IE can't find one doesn't send one to the server. IIS then complains about it with a 403.7 because IE didn't send a client certificate.

So you need to get a client (sometimes known as SMIME) certificate from your CA and install it into your personal store.

If you look at the details of your existing certificates it should show:

> Enhanced Key Usage: Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)

what you need there is:

> Enhanced Key Usage: 
>   Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
>   Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)

Comment: Thanks, I did that. I have a client and server auth in the cert I added to the local store. It prompts me asking which cert to use, and for permission to read the cert. Then responds with a 403...

Comment: Good, at least IE asks you for the client cert and you have that now, do you still get a 403.7?

Comment: No, it's actually a 403.13 now. I verified that the server can contact the CRL...

Comment: 403.13 is Client certificate revoked - If you just created that cert, wait a few hours. The Substatus codes are always worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks, turned out there was an issue with the revocation server! You helped a lot!